# Toggle on click hide by default

Tags: jquery

I use jQuery toggle to hide a div on click.
But I want the div be hidden by default.
How can I fix that?

I use this code:

```
$('.fold_reply').click(function() {
    $('.reply').toggle(500)
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z9rGz/307/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a css rule to set the `display` to `none`

```
.reply{display: none;}
```

Demo

```js
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(function($){
  $('.fold_reply').click(function() {
    $('.reply').toggle(500)
  });
});
```

```css
.reply {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="reply">
    Some content
    <br />
    Some more content
</div>

<button class="fold_reply">Fold</button>
```

Comment: But now my javascript is conflicting. How do I need to add $.noConflict();?

Comment: @Jelle, why do you need 2 versions of Jquery?

Comment: @ArunPJohny Why the jQuery.noConflict(); ? can u clarify in your answer ?

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik OP said there is a `$.noConflict()`(in the comments above)

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 : As @Arun P Johny already wrote : add css `display : none;`

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/z9rGz/309/)

Option 2 : Hide div using jquery : `$('.reply').hide();`

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/z9rGz/308/)